# Why won't SQL let me delete this foreign key?

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, db2

I'm trying to remove a foreign key from a SQL table, but it isn't working for some reason.

```
ALTER TABLE PETS
DROP FOREIGN KEY OWNER_NAME
```

But the above doesn't work - I don't get it. There isn't much syntax to mess up on, and `PETS` does have a foreign key `OWNER_NAME` to another table. What gives?

Pets table:

```
CREATE TABLE PETS
(
  NAME VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  BIRTH_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
  OWNER_NAME VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (NAME),
  FOREIGN KEY (OWNER_NAME) REFERENCES OWNER ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

ERROR RECIEVED: "OWNER_NAME" is an undefined name.

Comment: show us the table create statement for PETS please, and post the error you receive

Comment: also, what SQL are you on? MYSQL?

Comment: @David I'm not entirely sure. I'm using DB2, if that means anything.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax for dropping a foreign key is:

```
   ALTER TABLE table
      DROP FOREIGN KEY fk_name
```

In your example (that shows how the foreign key constraint is created, `OWNER_NAME` is *not* the name of the foreign key -- that is the name of the column in the PETS table that is used to reference the OWNER table.

Because you don't specify a specific name for the constraint in the CREATE TABLE statement, it will have a system generated name, which will look something like SQL110213181225320.

You can find the name of the constraint by looking at SYSCAT.REFERENCES:

```
   SELECT constname, fk_colnames
   FROM   syscat.references
   WHERE  tabschema = 'YOURSCHEMA'
     AND  tabname = 'PETS'
```

Then, you can drop your foreign key using the appropriate value of CONSTNAME from this query:

ALTER TABLE pets
      DROP FOREIGN KEY SQL110213181225320;

FYI, if you want to have a more normal name for the foreign key constraint, you can define it in the CREATE TABLE statement:

```
CREATE TABLE PETS
(
  NAME VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  BIRTH_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
  OWNER_NAME VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (NAME),
  CONSTRAINT FK_OWNER 
     FOREIGN KEY (OWNER_NAME) 
     REFERENCES OWNER 
     ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

If you do this, then you'll see that the query against SYSCAT.REFERENCES will return 'FK_OWNER'.